# Overwrite existing database

Tags: android, database, filestream

I got a database helper class that i got from [reigndesign.com](http://reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/), and i have it running fine. the problem is when i edit my database sqlbrowser and place it in my assets folder it wont replace my existing database, because in this databasehelper class it will only copy the database from the asset folder if it does not exist, My question is, what will i add to this helper class for it to over write my existing database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete your existing database first with `Context.deleteDatabase()` ([docs link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteDatabase%28java.lang.String%29)).